# Can I change the icon title on the iPhone home screen without changing the application name?

Tags: iphone

The name of an app we are developing is longer than can fit under the icon on the home screen, but it looks fine everywhere else it appears in the UI (like when a popup appears asking you if you want to delete it, in the settings app, etc.).

Is there any way to specify a different string for these different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for localized application names, I'm not aware of any option to specify different application names for different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify two different bundle names in your Info.plist:

[CFBundleDisplayName](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-110725):

> CFBundleDisplayName (String) specifies
>   the display name of the bundle. If you
>   support localized names for your
>   bundle, include this key in both your
>   information property list file and in
>   the InfoPlist.strings files of your
>   language subdirectories. If you
>   localize this key, you should also
>   include a localized version of the
>   CFBundleName key.

[CFBundleName](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-109585):

> CFBundleName (String) identifies the
>   short name of the bundle. This name
>   should be less than 16 characters long
>   and be suitable for displaying in the
>   menu bar and the application’s Info
>   window. You can include this key in
>   the InfoPlist.strings file of an
>   appropriate .lproj subdirectory to
>   provide localized values for it. If
>   you localize this key, you should also
>   include the key “CFBundleDisplayName.”

In Xcode these show up as "Bundle display name" and "Bundle name" respectively.

So just change the value of Bundle name to a shortened form and see if the dashboard uses that instead of the longer Bundle display name

Comment: I've done this, and the CFBundleDisplayName *will* change the home screen text displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the verification Tim, I'll remove my hesitation statement.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try it out and see if it does what I hope you're saying it does!

Comment: Hmm... didn't work.  Looks like it takes the Bundle Display Name wherever it's shown within the OS.  I didn't see anywhere that the Bundle Name was used.

Comment: While this answer has correct information, it doesn't really answer the question. CFBundleDisplayName changed the name everywhere, the original question asked about specifying different strings for home screen and regular use.