# App title within settings application different from title on home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings

Is this possible? Basically, I want to name my app Foo on the home screen, and BarFoo within the settings application on the device.  I did find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841583/can-i-change-the-icon-title-on-the-iphone-home-screen-without-changing-the-appli), which suggests it's not possible, without quite saying as much in so many words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Apple uses the same string in both locations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change your application's bundle display name.  You will find that in your info.plist under CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: That changes both of them.  I want them to be different.